# How to make an index

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make a table of content for this web page I am making (the project is still offline for the time being).

Now I already know most of what I have to do (text boxes, lists, the CSS, etc) however I don't want the links going to new pages but rather it send the user to certain parts of the page like in a wiki.

Any idea on how one would code something like that?

Comment: They're called anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<a href="#jump">Jump to a section</a>
```

Then in the location to jump to:

```
<a name="jump"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [anchor link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) (or bookmarks)

The code will be:

```
<a href="#my-div>Link to 'my div'</a>

<div id="my-div"></div>
```

That link will scroll the page until the element with the corresponding ID